# Images in Documents directory couldn't be loaded via <Img> tag on iOS but Tmp

Tags: html, ios, image, cordova, uiimagepickercontroller

I use Cordova image picker plugins to get images from camera roll on iOS. If the image returned is in the *Documents* directory, namely its full path like '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXX-XXX-XXX/Documents/IMG_001.JPG', then the image couldn't be displayed by a html tag like `<img src="file://**>`. 
But if the image returned is from the *tmp* directory, it works well with the `<img>` tag.

What are the possible reasons to make the difference, and how to make images from *Documents* directory shows as well in html?

BTW, the two different returned images paths are from two different image picker plugins respectively.

Comment: Just tested, after moved from Documents to tmp, images could be loaded correctly.